# Angular 4 - display date from database

Tags: mysql, database, angular

I need display data in table from MySql database, but I dont know how it do this.
I tried found something example or example application with source code, but I nothing found.
Maybe someone help me with this?
I tried with node.js express:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var https = require('https');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "https://adress to database",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: "db"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

But i get error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Comment: Please provide more details, like: How are dates kept within the DB, how your Web client communicates with the DB, what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple way to get data from mySQL and export it as json:

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'db location',
    user: 'username od db',
    password: 'something',
    database: 'yourdatabase',
    port:3306

});


// define rute
var apiRoutes = express.Router();

var port = 9000; 
apiRoutes.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.json({ message: 'API works' });
});
apiRoutes.get('/data', function (req, res, next) {

    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

        if (err) {
            console.error("error hapened: " + err);
        }

        var query = "SELECT * FROM imena ORDER BY id ASC";

        var table = ["imena"];

        query = mysql.format(query, table);

        connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    list_users: rows
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// starting
app.listen(port);
console.log('API radi @ port:' + ' ' + port);
```

But i still suggest that you start using noSQL databases like firebase because of they are simple and faster.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show data from MySQL Database, you need to provide application interface(s) to Angular environment and only then Angular can use the data. There are few techniques in which you can design interfaces, REST is the most popular though.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that Angular is Front-End framework and it can only send requests to backend such as Node js, PHP etc.Thus, first you need to chose your backend. Node is popular with express js module, but if you still don't have mySQL set, go for firebase real time database. If you decide node js => express => mySQL check tutorial online.

Comment: I understand all, but I dont know how to use my node js script in Angular 4?